# Is this code indentation edit really irrelevant?

Tags: discussion

Reviewing first posts, I tried to fix code indentation in an answer, but stackoverflow blocked me with the "edits should be at least 6 chars" message.

Is my edit really irrelevant and should be blocked?

related answer: [Converting an array to positive indicator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551825/converting-an-array-to-positive-indicator/38998736#38998736)

**content before edit:**

> import numpy as np a = np.array([-2,4,3,-1,2]) np.where(a>0,1,0)

**content after edit:**

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([-2,4,3,-1,2])
np.where(a>0,1,0)
```

Comment: It's not that it's irrelevant, it's that whitespace changes don't count for the character limit. The system can't tell how important the change is. It's rare that the only thing that needs fixed in a post that needs code formatting changes is... Well, the code formatting. That answer looks like a poor answer to begin with... It might not be worth your time to edit it.

Comment: I could add dummy text like: you can use this code, but, the code seems to be enough in the context.

Comment: Actually, looking at it again, the answer is 1) really late and 2) almost exactly the same code as the answer in the accepted question. Not knowing the language, I don't know how significant the `,1,0` is in the last line of code... But that _really_ doesn't look like an answer worth your time. And I don't recommend adding dummy text. It'd likely get your suggested edit rejected.

Comment: Maybe this particular example isn't terribly convincing, but I remember seeing a few seemingly interesting questions where the code was so badly indented the eyes hurt... and in Python one space can make difference between working and non-working code. It would be nice to be able to salvage such posts... well, now all I think I could do is downvote and comment 'Fix your code indentation'.

Comment: @rafalmp: _"in Python one space can make difference between working and non-working code"_ -- which is, for better or for worse, why one can't go around fixing indentation in Python code in questions. Such edits could materially change the actual meaning or context of the question.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I had the same thought minutes after your comment, so I decided to flesh it out in a full answer.

Comment: @Kendra I think you're right - the `np.where` could/should have just been a comment on the accepted answer, rather than a full answer on its own.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Code indentation isn't irrelevant.

It can break or make a question (/answer).

The problem is that the edit was only whitespace. The system doesn't count whitespace as a part of the edit, when suggested edits are concerned. This is to prevent users from bypassing the character limitation when suggesting minor edits.

For now, all you can really do it comment on the answer, and leave the edit up to a 2k+ rep user.

Comment: So 2k+ rep user can make those minor edits? Now It makes sense to me.

Comment: Indeed. [When you get 2k rep](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit), edits no longer need to be reviewed, so the restriction is removed.

Comment: I took this opportunity to demonstrate.

Comment: In cases where indentation can "make or break" a question, I suggest against editing in the first place. Please see my answer for a more detailed opinion:)

Comment: @CubeJockey My hero! You are so manly. ;)

Answer (score 8):

It has [just now been noted by Peter Duniho in a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332649/is-this-code-indentation-edit-really-irrelevant?cb=1#comment385164_332649), but I think one aspect is important enough for making it a full answer.

*In most cases*, indentation might only be a matter of aesthetics, and still we can argue whether edits like this are substantial. However, *in this specific case the language was Python*. Python happens to be a language where whitespace has syntactic significance. Newlines (or semicolons) separate statements, and levels of indentation (rather than braces) mark blocks. Surely there are other languages with the same odd feature, for instance [ABC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABC_(programming_language)), one of the predecessors of Python.

So here's my suggestion: *never* edit whitespace in Python code (or other languages, where whitespace matters). In an answer, you might "just" break something; in a question, you might inadvertently cause the very error in question to disappear.

Note that in your specific case, the final rendered code in the original answer was actually invalid due to missing whitespace, and your edit would've fixed it. But this is the rarer scenario, and it's better to err on the side of safety. If you see a language where whitespace is important (mostly Python in case of Stack Overflow), don't touch the code!

---

To serve as further warning, consider this mildly contorted bit of Python code:

```
doit = True
if doit:
    for n in list_of_numbers:
        if n%2==0:
             print("List contains an even number.")
             break
    else:
        print("List contains only odd numbers.")
```

This will print whether the iterable called `list_of_numbers` contains only odd numbers, and will short-circuit if it finds an even number. A well-meaning braces-user might think to "fix" the indentation of the `else` clause, and edit the corresponding post to reflect this, thereby breaking the code. Similarly, if the user posting this piece of code doesn't use proper code formatting, it will be very hard for somebody unfamiliar with the language to get the <s>indented intendation</s> intended indentation right.

Comment: I *rarely* edit someone's Python code for indentation, unless it's clear that the code formatting actually did get horked up - which is usually indicated by a `def` or `class` on the first line that's flush with the rest of the code, and the OP *not* mentioning something like a syntax/indent error. Most of the time I simply leave a note with the `[edit]` shortcut and tell them to fix their markdown.

Comment: *or other languages, where whitespace* is syntactically significant: FORTRAN and Haskell would be the other two main examples I think

Comment: While I agree with exercising caution with whitespace significant languages, in the specific case the OP asks about, it's clear the user who posted the answer originally just didn't have any idea how to format code. There's no semicolons separating the statements, only newlines.

Comment: @JGreenwell and Cobol - cause we see a ton of that here on SO ;)

Comment: I disagree. This particular edit *didn't* change the indentation or the meaning. It changed the formatting. If you look through [the revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38998736/revisions) you can see that the source was perfectly valid python that was rendered weird, due to the answerer not understanding SO markdown. Now you can see the answer as the answerer intended.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem (DR. Ham) that's exactly why I wrote "*Note that in your specific case, the final rendered code in the original answer was actually invalid due to missing whitespace, and your edit would've fixed it*" above, I wasn't saying that this particular edit was bad. But I feel it's worth emphasizing that whitespace edits should be handled only very carefully in Python and similar languages, because code-breaking indentation edits are all too common.